# Actors Integration with Amazon SQS

Tags: akka, amazon-sqs

I was wondering if there are any existing solutions out there of replacing the mailboxes of actors with Amazon Web Services SQS service. Seems to me to be the intuitive thing to do to make the Akka framework cloud-friendly. I'm interested if anyone has experience in doing this or if there are plans in the future for the Akka framework in general to begin leveraging what the cloud has to offer, or if Akka will continue to stay cloud agnostic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon SQS, and any other message bus for that matter, is far to heavy-weight to be a replacement for Akka mailboxes, which are just in-memory queues. Keep in mind that actors are a very general model of computation, not only for messaging between systems, but also used in-process.

It's not a problem to combine SQS and Akka, though. I suggest you have a look at the [SQS Alpakka connector](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/sqs.html), which will give you an Akka Streams interface to SQS.

Comment: Thanks that's what I'm after I think.